# Passing Parameters In Abstract Method

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have an abstract class in Java that has this method called

```java
public abstract void onImageRendered(BufferedImage render)
```

I want the user to access the rendered image with this method. I have another method called

```java
public void render()
```

That renders the image. The buffered image in the abstract method should not be any image but the rendered image from this method.
How do I pass the rendered image from that method as the parameter of the abstract method?
Here is my code:

```java
public static void render(Scene scene) throws MORISIllegalMethodCallException{
    if(propertiesAreSet){
        Camera activeCamera = scene.getActiveCamera();

        for (int x = 0; x < activeCamera.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < activeCamera.getHeight(); y++) {
                Ray ray = Ray.shootAt(activeCamera.getOrigin(), new Vector(x - activeCamera.getWidth()/2.0, activeCamera.getHeight()/2.0 - y, -(activeCamera.getHeight()/2.0)/Math.tan(activeCamera.getFov() * 0.5)).mul(activeCamera.getDirection()).normalize());
                for (Renderable object : scene.getSceneObjects()) {
                    if (object.intersects(ray)){
                        //Assign colors to buffered image object "this.image" and do other necessary things
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else {
        throw new MORISIllegalMethodCallException("The method moris.renderer.MORISRT.setProperties(int, double) should be executed before invoking the method moris.renderer.MORISRT.render(moris.scene.Scene)");
    }
}

abstract void onImageRendered(BufferedImage renderedImage);//Here, the BufferedImage object should be "this.image"
```

The rendered image is something like this:
[image: Here is the rendered image]
I tried searching StackOverflow for similar questions and also checked some other sources but they didn't seem to help.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more information, ideally a [mcve] - and you might want to (re)read [ask]. Right now it's hard to tell what your problem is but I assume you're having some difficulty grasping the basics of Java while trying to tackle advanced topics like ui, composition etc. As an example, `void render()` doesn't return anything so how should we know where that image is you're refering to and how this could/should be passed to `onImageRendered()` (which btw looks like a listener method and thus it depends on where you registered the listener).

Comment: Yes, that is true. I never work with abstraction in my programs and this is my first time using the concept in an actual program. I will update the question to provide more clarity.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is what you want, but try calling `onImageRendered(this.image)` from within `render()` (which of course should not be a static method or it wouldn't be able to access `this.image` anyway.

Comment: Have you written a subclass to override the `onImageRendered` abstract method?

Comment: @k314159 Yes I have a Main class to run this

Comment: @Thomas Will it work?

Comment: Well, I still don't have enough information about your code so I can't tell whether this is what you want, whether the rest of your code fits the approach etc. - so I can't tell whether this _will_ work. If you're doing it correctly it _should_ work though. Just try it.

Comment: Btw, what exactly should `onImageRendered(...)` do in the sub classes? Is this just for notifications that could even be processed by other parts of your code? The name `onXxx()` looks like it's meant to notify any listeners for the fact/event/notification that the image has been rendered and then do with that information what ever they want. But if this is your intent, then the design should be adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
abstract void onImageRendered(BufferedImage renderedImage);//Here, the BufferedImage object should be "this.image"
```

First thing to say is that you are trying to add an implementation detail to an abstract method. That is wrong by definition. If it is an abstract method implementation is delegated to subclasses. But that just means that you are free to use `this.image` in every subclass. What you can do is, in your abstract class, is having a...

```java
protected BufferedImage image;
```

...that you can reference from every sublcass as `this.image`.

But you will have to change the signature of the method `render()`. It cannot be `static` if you want to reference `this`. `static` methods can only access `static` attributes, and `this` always references an instance attribute.

**Update**

You can call the abstract method in the abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    private BufferedImage image;

    public void render() {
        // ...
        onImageRendered(this.image);
        // ...
    }

    public abstract void onImageRendered(BufferedImage renderedImage);
}
```

```java
public class MyConcreteClass extends MyAbstractClass {
    @Override
    public abstract void onImageRendered(BufferedImage renderedImage) {
        // do stuff with renderedImage, which will always be the image
        // in the rendered metho called on the parent class
    }
}
```

Comment: But how does the JavaFX `start(Stage primaryStage)` method work? It is an abstract method from the abstract class Application. The start method has the `Stage` object which we can operate upon. I want similar functionality in my program. The `BufferedImage` object needs to be the rendered image from my class that is created in the `render()` method. Is there a way to pass the rendered image to the abstract function later?

Comment: JavaFX `Application` instance lifecycle is managed internally but the Java FX runtime. You just have to override the `start` method, but the instance of `Stage` is created and managed by the JavaFX runtime.

Here you don't have a runtime that perform any _magic_ under the hood. You have to do it yourself.

Plase, provide the `Main` class, the abstract class signature, and all the code involved in instancing and sublcassing, and most important, how and from where the method `onImageRendered` is supposed to be called.

Comment: So can I call `onImageRendered(this.image)` inside the `render()` function?

Comment: Of course. As long as `render(...)` is not static. You can call static methods from instance methods, but not the other way round.